# Java swing JButton usage, not responding

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

first timer here.

I am trying to use swing for the first time. My buttons do nothing when clicked. I could not find the mistake. I have 2 buttons, one is Add and one is Clear. Add will add the text in textfields to a file later, and clear will clear all the textfields. But buttond do not respond.  I do not see the warning Message Box "Please fill all fields!"  or  "Successfully Added"

Here is my code:

```
public class CustomerList {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField txtCompanyName;
    private JTextField txtSector;
    private JTextField txtCity;
    private JTextField txtAddress;
    private JTextField txtNotes;
    private JButton btnAdd;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    CustomerList window = new CustomerList();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public CustomerList() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 646, 469);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblCompanyName = new JLabel("Company Name");
        lblCompanyName.setBounds(12, 27, 104, 16);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblCompanyName);

        JLabel lblSector = new JLabel("Sector");
        lblSector.setBounds(12, 56, 56, 16);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblSector);

        JLabel lblCountry = new JLabel("Country");
        lblCountry.setBounds(12, 85, 56, 16);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblCountry);

        JLabel lblCity = new JLabel("City");
        lblCity.setBounds(12, 114, 56, 16);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblCity);

        JLabel lblAddress = new JLabel("Address");
        lblAddress.setBounds(12, 143, 56, 16);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblAddress);

        JLabel lblNotes = new JLabel("Notes");
        lblNotes.setBounds(12, 251, 56, 16);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNotes);

        txtCompanyName = new JTextField();
        txtCompanyName.setBounds(128, 24, 224, 22);
        frame.getContentPane().add(txtCompanyName);
        txtCompanyName.setColumns(10);

        txtSector = new JTextField();
        txtSector.setBounds(128, 53, 224, 22);
        frame.getContentPane().add(txtSector);
        txtSector.setColumns(10);

        JComboBox comboCountry = new JComboBox();
        comboCountry.addItem("Select");
        comboCountry.addItem("Turkey");
        comboCountry.addItem("Afghanistan");
        comboCountry.addItem("Albania");
        comboCountry.addItem("Algeria");
        comboCountry.addItem("Andorra");
        comboCountry.addItem("Angola");
        comboCountry.addItem("Antigua and Barbuda");


        comboCountry.setToolTipText("Country");
        comboCountry.setBounds(128, 82, 224, 22);
        frame.getContentPane().add(comboCountry);

        txtCity = new JTextField();
        txtCity.setBounds(128, 111, 224, 22);
        frame.getContentPane().add(txtCity);
        txtCity.setColumns(10);

        txtAddress = new JTextField();
        txtAddress.setBounds(128, 140, 224, 99);
        frame.getContentPane().add(txtAddress);
        txtAddress.setColumns(10);

        txtNotes = new JTextField();
        txtNotes.setBounds(128, 248, 224, 99);
        frame.getContentPane().add(txtNotes);
        txtNotes.setColumns(10);


        /*
        JButton btnAdd = new JButton("Add");
        */
        btnAdd = new JButton("Add");

        btnAdd.setBounds(388, 23, 97, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnAdd);


        btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                if((txtCompanyName.getText().isEmpty())||(txtSector.getText().isEmpty())||(txtCity.getText().isEmpty())||(txtAddress.getText().isEmpty())||(txtNotes.getText().isEmpty())||(comboCountry.getSelectedItem().equals("Select")))
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill all fields!");
                else        
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully Added");



            }
        });



        JButton btnClear = new JButton("Clear");
        btnClear.setBounds(497, 23, 97, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnClear);


        btnClear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                txtCompanyName.setText(null);
                txtSector.setText(null);
                txtCity.setText(null);
                txtAddress.setText(null);
                txtNotes.setText(null);
                comboCountry.setSelectedItem("Select");


            }
        });

        JButton btnClose = new JButton("Close");
        btnClose.setBounds(497, 81, 97, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnClose);
        btnClose.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);             

            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

Comment: does btn add Print Yes anyway?

Comment: It seems that your button "Add" should print "Yes" on the standard output /console and show dialog "Successfully Added". Since you are not adding anything else via its listener, it won't be modifying any state information.

Comment: sorry, "yes" thing was just for a try to see if it is working or not. I deleted it now. The problem is, I do not see the warning Message Box "Please fill all fields!"

Comment: Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me, but using `null` for the parentComponent parameter of `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()` may behave differently on different platforms.  That is, maybe the dialog are showing, but just not where you expect.

Since you have a parent frame, why not specify it?

```
if ((txtCompanyName.getText().isEmpty()) || (txtSector.getText().isEmpty()) || (txtCity.getText().isEmpty()) || (txtAddress.getText().isEmpty())
                            || (txtNotes.getText().isEmpty()) || (comboCountry.getSelectedItem().equals("Select"))) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Please fill all fields!");
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Successfully Added");
}
```